# Main arguments in flex-bison

Tags: compiler-construction, bison, flex-lexer

Sorry for my English.
I need to take the value of the parameters of the main function.
I said in Bison:

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
```

I compile in Windows:

```
file.exe <input.txt
```

=>

```
argc = 1
```

and

```
argv = "file.exe"
```

Why?
Thank you.

Comment: What does this have to do with flex or bison?

Answer (score 1):

Try "file.exe input.txt", without the "<": argv[1] will be "input.txt".